# How can use variable selectively in JS?

Tags: javascript, variables

I want make variable's value selectively.

For example :

> IE9 ~ : var a = document.getElementsByClassName('abc');
>
> ~ IE8 : var a = document.querySelectorAll('.abc');

So I made an IF sentences. Below is it.

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName) {
    gnbLink = document.getElementsByClassName('gnb_a');
} else {
    gnbLink = document.querySelectorAll('.gnb_a');
}
```

But it is not working. In this code, value of gnbLink is always `document.querySelector~~`.

How can make value of variable selectively?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: Why aren't you just always using `querySelectorAll` in this case? It has better semantics (and different ones too, the returned NodeList is frozen) and compatibility anyway.

Comment: Because getElementsByClassName is faster than querySelectorAll. (http://jsperf.com/getelementsbyclassname-vs-queryselectorall/18) So I like getElementsByClassName than querySelectorAll.

Comment: @goJson Is speed really that important in this case? I would just use `querySelectorAll` in all cases until I found that it was actually a bottleneck.

Comment: Your code seems correct (even if I would add a `var` declaration outside the if and use `typeof document.getElementsByClassName !== "undefined"` for testing the condition).